# Code for filtering multiple criteria in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new to SQL.
I Have this table, how to write a code to filter the rows following these criteria.
Each product filter by column item_revenue only shows the months with at least four positives or four negatives.
So the result should show only product_A for February, product_B for January and February.

[Table to filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pKGy.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select product_name, month
from mytable
group by product_name, month
having countif(item_revenue > 0) >= 4 OR countif(item_revenue < 0) >= 4
```